# create oracle 19c docker version without CDB

Tags: oracle, docker

I'm creating a single instance by [this](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md) instructions. Everything works well but the DB is created with CDB. I would like to create a simple-non-cdb oracle instance. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change those in `dbca.rsp.tmpl`

```
createAsContainerDatabase=false
numberOfPDBs=0
```

Comment: I was able to set the numberofPDBs=0, however when I run the docker using the following
command 
<docker run --name orclnoncdb -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_SID=orcl -e ORACLE_PWD=0rclPassW0rd -e INIT_SGA_SIZE=2048 -e INIT_PGA_SIZE=512 -e ORACLE_EDITION=enterprise  -e ENABLE_TCPS=true orcl_plain:21.3.0>

i get the following error, what am i missing please..

[FATAL] [DBT-10333] Container database (CDB) creation option is not selected.
   CAUSE: Non-CDB creation is not supported.
   ACTION: Make sure container database (CDB) option is selected.

Thanks
Bala